# How to get kerberos authentication on spark's executor

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, kerberos

For some reason, I need to build a connection to access hbase in a mapPartition. hbase/hadoop both have kerberos enabled. the Spark application is also running under kerberos.

The hbase connection is created through `ConnectionFactory.createConnection(configuration);`.
Which will get the user via `AuthUtil.loginClient(conf)`, but the problem is that the user we get here is the unauthenticated user: `xxx(auth: simple)`. Continuing to drill down into the code shows that this user is obtained via `ugi = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser();`.

Running `UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser()` on driver and executor gives different results:

- driver: `xxxx:(auth:KERBEROS)`
- executor: `xxxx:(auth:SIMPLE)`

Obviously, the executor is not globally authenticated, causing hbase to fetch the unauthenticated user.

With some information, I can know that spark's executor is getting token information via driver:`SparkHadoopUtil.get.addDelegationTokens`, instead of authenticating directly.

So how can I get this token on executor and use it to create hbase's connection?

## Update

I'm complicating the matter. Simply setting the parameter `spark.security.credentials.hbase.enabled` to true solves the problem.

However, I would appreciate it if someone could tell me detailed information about this parameter, e.g. how the executor gets this authentication information and uses it.